# Generic class type java

Tags: java, generics

I want to write one generic object mapping json to java, for insert went is needed.

So i was making the next code

```
public class JSONConverter<T> {

    public String getStringJSON(T obj{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        if(obj!=null){
            try {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        //mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);

    }

    public T getObject(String stringJSON){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.readValue(stringJSON, T.class);

    }
}
```

But my problem is that the T.class is not working, how i can get the class of one generic value? because if i put  `getObject(String stringJSON, class<T> clazzT)` i have to add always class and if i put like a property class clazzT in the object i will have a null pointerException.

So how i can fix the problem, for use only the definition of the object like Converter?

And i see in some implementation of REST like easyRest and CXF, that they use the Class of the type for make the tranformation between String and Object, like

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response someService(SomeClass obj)
```

They use some automatique way, i want to have the one class similar like that

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: No, and the OP asks for help to make it compile (and work).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `Class<T>` as a parameter to the `getObject()` method, so that you are able to fetch `T`'s Runtime `Class` type:

```
public T getObject(String stringJSON, Class<T> clazz){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.readValue(stringJSON, clazz);
}
```

And also, re-factor all the references to the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because of type erasure.

What you **can** do is to bind your generic type with an interface:

```
public class JSONConverter<T extends IMyInterface>
```

Then you can de-serialize as:

```
mapper.readValue(stringJSON, IMyInterface.class);
```

You might even be able to annotate your classes implementing `IMyInterface` so that the sub-type is known by Jackson at de-serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Tipically, the type is passed as parameter:

```
public T getObject(String stringJSON, Class<T> clazz){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.readValue(stringJSON, clazz);
}
```

Actually, there is a way to obtain T.class runtime by reflection, but I don't recommend it you.

**EDIT**

Obtain `T.class` on runtime:

```
  private Class<T> type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass())
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Sometimes I get NPE using that, I don't recommend it.

Comment: Can you show how we can obtain T.class using reflection as you claimed?

Comment: Done. I insist, from experience, these way is not reliable.